# Trouble with MQL4 concept of a DEFAULT [GRAPH] selection

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

I have an university assignment for some scripts in MQL4 for MetaTrader and I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of some concepts that are frequently being used there.

The author of said assignment asked us to create a function counting all readings in a chart. While experimenting I've come across some chart functions but they're all operating on a default chart that I am unable to set.

Is there a resource or a person here that would explain those well to a person not associated with stock exchange at all? The documentation assumes the reader has some degree of knowledge in this subject while I do not.

Perhaps someone can tell me how to set a default chart and how to proceed from there.

Comment: I would be happy to answer your questions. Could you provide a link to the Course / University you wrote about?

Answer (score 1):

### Step A: Visual (des) orientation on screen:

MetaTrader Terminal 4 is a main-programme of a framework, that uses one or many individual, mutually-independent, one-and-the-only-one TradingINSTRUMENT-focused [Graph]-s on its common MT4-main-screen.

You might have noticed, the collection of currently active ( displayed ) [Graph]-s may have different layouts ( appearances ):

- a full-screen mode ( ignoring the MT4-process-window )
- a TAB-formatted mode ( stack of [Graph]-s "inside" MT4-process-window )
- a tiled-mode ( vertically, horizontally, in a grid-fashion, in a manually adjusted, semi-covering each other chaos )

[image]

---

### Step B: What is a [Graph] useful for?

Besides an elementary visualisation of the `TradingINSTRUMENT` prices and other details, the `[Graph]` is a **basic "environment"**, into which some other ***programmable* services** have access.

MT4 supports several types of such programmable services --

1. a **Script**
2. an **Expert Advisor**
3. a **Custom Indicator**

Without going into deeper details, all these have a common base, the programming language -- MQL4.

---

### Step C: So how does the MQL4-code "define" a default graph?

Simply put, the only way to make an MQL4 programme work is to let it run on one [Graph].

This means, that the MQL4 code, **the programme, has one**, a-priori given, [Graph] to which it belongs -- this is the **code-relative-`DEFAULT-[Graph]`.**

For many years, over about a decade, your MQL4 code simply **was not allowed to decide on which [Graph]** it would output it's GUI-objects, as it had access only to the very [Graph] it was already launched at.

Recent MQL4 builds ( a.k.a. *New*-MQL4.56789 ) started to "allow *New*MQL4-code" to indirectly access and manipulate "foreign" [Graph]-s.

This syntax-option is an extremely dangerous dual-edge sword, once debugging comes into one's necessity -- how to decide which MQL4-code-unit was responsible for a faulty operation?

So, even when there is such chance, the safer-side for your MQL4 functions is to **always refer to this very same `DEFAULT-[Graph] == 0`** ( which may have, if you create such, **`sub-windows`** ( may see in upper-right USDJPY,H4 [Graph] above for details ), with adjustable drawing(s) of `CustomIndicator`(s) et al, but all these belong to the same [Graph] ) and your GUI-code is compact, understandable and without principally un-debuggable side-effects magically appearing on screen just by some "foreign" process(es) intervene(s) into your "own" `DEFAULT-[Graph]` **scene/graph-<sub>( Anarchy-FREE )</sub>-`GUI`-composition**.

[image]

For syntax-specific details, re-read the Help-file available in MetaEditor IDE.

As you read, the New-MQL4.56789 features are new even to HELP-editors, and many code-snipetts are inconsistent with both an absolute and an old ( relative ) [Graph]-id references ( ref. red arrows ).

[image]